# Responsive website looks different in mobile browser

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am developing website for **480px to 768px** wide screen. when I check website on my **PC Chrome** on browser width 480px, it looks perfect. But when I see same website on mobile which has resolution **720x1280** using Chrome browser it looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is helped the OP:

Although the mobile device has a resolution of 720x1280 the device might claim otherwise when it's width is being [queried](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml). Width of your device(in px) can be different than resolution(in px).

Comment: I should develop website which can support minimum 320px. I was developing for 480px. I also found that my device has 360px width in pixel and 720px resolution. Pixel density should be consider.

Comment: @NizamKazi I am facing the same problem, I am unable to understand...how did you fixed this issue?

Comment: @Y.R please refer the link I have shared in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Include this meta tag in your head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:


The main problem is in the Bootstrap.

I am not an expert in Bootstrap. But the problem that I see is that half of your code isn't working properly. When I viewed page source, a particular section in footer isn't displayed.

I think the problem is with Bootstrap classes.

I can't find many classes available in Bootstrap 3 that you are using like `footer-nav` , `bigtext` , `icon-box` , `color-blue`, `footer-social pull-left` and many more.

Maybe you need to take a look at complete Bootstrap 3 Classes reference:

https://gist.github.com/mrcybermac/9175466

Also I think you're overusing `container-fluid` . Try using `container` , because we can't assign full width to each element that we make. And make sure you don't nest one `container` inside another `container`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my problem is not those css or layout. I written those css to customize default look of bootstrap template. My problem is when I see website on desktop browser by resizing it, it looks pefrect. But doesn't look same on mobile browser which has same width.

Comment: O.K. I got your point but still the css that you are using (main.css) isn't working properly. It's not looking perfect when you resizes the desktop browser window. So, maybe you should just make better use of media queries in main.css to get it right.